# Show a colum of the last row of table?

Tags: sql

I have a table in sql and I want to show a colum of the last row of table, how is it possible? i used `SELECT TOP 1 id FROM .$table ORDER BY id DESC` but no answer.

Comment: add to query end `LIMIT 1`

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @maximkou could you write full query please?

Comment: `SELECT MAX(id)`? If you want that id+1 for a new id, better use autoincr key generating and retrieve key later with mysql function.

Comment: In SQL there is really no such thing as "the last row of table". In SQL you have to think of the table as a set in no particular order (in object-oriented parlance, as a "bag").  You impose order on the set by sorting it by one or more columns. The ID column is not guaranteed to reflect the chronological order in which the columns were entered.  For this prupose you should really use a DateTime datatype and a default value representing the current date-time.  If you need the most recently used ID, then better to use autoincrement or whatever function the implementation offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the LIMIT as 1 like

```
SELECT TOP 1 id FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Makesure that $table is your table name.

Answer (score 0):

- **In MS Access:**

  ```
  SELECT TOP 1 id FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC
  ```
- **In MySQL:**

  ```
  SELECT id FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
  ```
- **In Oracle:**

  ```
  SELECT id FROM $table WHERE ROWNUM <=1 ORDER BY id
  ```
- **Or, you can do this:** *(based on [Joop Eggen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834271/show-a-colum-of-the-last-row-of-table#comment26030259_17834271))*

  ```
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM $table
  ```

Where `$table` is the name of your table.

*You may also want to check this [article on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp).*